# How do I assign a property to a reference assignment for a function (without using execute)

Tags: maxscript

I'm hoping to assign a property to a function for MAXScript.

Here's what I've tried:

```
fn getProp type: = (
  $.'type'
  )
getProp type:'pos'
```

I would like to pass the `pos` property as a variable to the function `getProp` and retrieve it as the same as this code:

`$.pos`.

---

For another example to get the scale of the selected object the code would look like this:

```
fn getProp type: = (
  $.'type'
  )
getProp type:'rotation'
```

---

Here's the execute version that I don't want to do as an example:

```
fn getProp type: = (
  execute("$."+type)
  )
getProp type:#pos
-- will return: [25.051,-115.88,0]
```

#### Edit

Full code of what I want to achieve in its context with what works and what doesn't. See line 55.

```
try(destroydialog ::lvRolTest)catch()
rollout lvRolTest "Check Mate.."
(

  local  _lvSetItemsInvertProp, _lvSetItemsInvertPropNotWorking

  label         countLabelPrefix       "How many you say ?" across:3
  label         countLabelVal          ""
  checkButton   chkLvToggleAllButton   "Toggle All..."
  dotNetControl lv                     "ListView" width:270 height:535 pos:[10,30]

  on lvRolTest open do (
    lv.View                  = (dotNetClass "View").Details
    lv.FullRowSelect         = true
    lv.MultiSelect           = true
    lv.Checkboxes            = true
    lv.Columns.add           ("Items")

    lv.columns.item[0].width = lvRolTest.width-55

    for x=1 to 100 do (
      lv.BeginUpdate()
      local newLvItem = dotNetObject "ListViewItem" ("Item " + x as string)
      newLvItem.checked = true
      lv.EndUpdate()
      lv.items.add newLvItem
      )
    lv.Focus()
    countLabelVal.text = (lv.CheckedItems.count) as string
    )

  on chkLvToggleAllButton changed state do (
    if state do chkLvToggleAllButton.text         = "Toggle All Again..."

    -- This is working
    --     _lvSetItemsInvertProp ("lvRolTest" as string) ("lv" as string) prop:#Checked

    -- This is not
    _lvSetItemsInvertPropNotWorking lv prop:#Checked

    if not state do chkLvToggleAllButton.text     = "Toggle All..."
    countLabelVal.text = (lv.CheckedItems.count) as string
    lv.Focus()
    )

  -- This is working
  fn _lvSetItemsInvertProp rolArg lvArg prop:#Checked = (
    execute("for i = 0 to "+rolArg+"."+lvArg+".items.count-1 do (
      local item = "+rolArg+"."+lvArg+".items.item[i]
      if item."+prop+" == true then item."+prop+" = false else item."+prop+" = true
      )")
    )

  --   This is not
  fn _lvSetItemsInvertPropNotWorking ListView prop:#Checked = (
    for i = 0 to lvRolTest.lv.items.count-1 do (
      local item = getProperty (lvRolTest.lv.items.item[i]) prop
      if item == true then item = false else item = true
      )
    )

  )

createDialog lvRolTest 300 575 pos:[1850,700] style:#(#style_SysMenu, #style_ToolWindow, #style_resizing)
```

#### EDIT 2. Updated code with the solution as per Swordslayers comment below.

```
try(destroydialog ::lvRolTest)catch()
rollout lvRolTest "Check Mate.."
(

  local  _lvSetItemsInvertProp

  label         countLabelPrefix       "How many you say ?" across:3
  label         countLabelVal          ""
  checkButton   chkLvToggleAllButton   "Toggle All..."
  dotNetControl lv                     "ListView" width:270 height:535 pos:[10,30]

  on lvRolTest open do (
    lv.View                  = (dotNetClass "View").Details
    lv.FullRowSelect         = true
    lv.MultiSelect           = true
    lv.Checkboxes            = true
    lv.Columns.add           ("Items")

    lv.columns.item[0].width = lvRolTest.width-55

    for x=1 to 100 do (
      lv.BeginUpdate()
      local newLvItem = dotNetObject "ListViewItem" ("Item " + x as string)
      newLvItem.checked = true
      lv.EndUpdate()
      lv.items.add newLvItem
      )
    lv.Focus()
    countLabelVal.text = (lv.CheckedItems.count) as string
    )

  on chkLvToggleAllButton changed state do (
    if state do chkLvToggleAllButton.text         = "Toggle All Again..."
    if not state do chkLvToggleAllButton.text     = "Toggle All..."
    _lvSetItemsInvertProp lv prop:#Checked
    _lvSetItemsInvertProp lv prop:#Selected
    countLabelVal.text = (lv.CheckedItems.count) as string
    lv.Focus()
    )

  fn _lvSetItemsInvertProp lvArg prop:#Checked = (
    for i = 0 to lv.items.count-1 do (
      local bool = getProperty (lvArg.items.item[i]) prop
      setProperty (lvArg.items.item[i]) prop (not bool)
      )
    )

  )

createDialog lvRolTest 300 575 pos:[1850,700] style:#(#style_SysMenu, #style_ToolWindow, #style_resizing)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention several things at once, mapped function (which I don't see a trace of in the sample code and will thus ignore) and getting properties given a variable property name using your own function - surely you tried using [getProperty](https://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2017/ENU/?guid=__files_GUID_879ECFAD_7928_44B3_BCD7_276D53C89B52_htm):

```
getProperty $ type
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry that the terminology was not correct. I've modified the OP to show exactly where the problem is.

Comment: That's because you're setting the contents of the variable, not the property, use setProperty and you're done: 
`local bool = getProperty (lvRolTest.lv.items.item[i]) prop
setProperty (lvRolTest.lv.items.item[i]) prop (not bool)`

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll update the Q with the updated solution.